# Facebook Javascript Share UI include get variables in link

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api

I am using the facebook SDK to share a page link:

```
FB.ui({
        method: 'feed',
        link:  'http://freebirdevents.co.uk/test_results/?individual_result=1162',
        caption:$(this).data('message'),
}, function(response){});
```

However it is ignoring get parameter, I've tried URL encoding to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

> However it is ignoring get parameter

That’s because you are *telling it to*:

```
<link rel="canonical" href="http://freebirdevents.co.uk/test_results/" />
```

You *specified* here that the real URL for this piece of content is `http://freebirdevents.co.uk/test_results/`. Facebook follows that, and goes on to request *that* URL to get the relevant meta data from.

If you don’t want that – then don’t specify this as the canonical URL of the document.